# Where to get names of API_NAMES, API_VERSIONS

Tags: python, google-drive-api

In Google's `apiclient`, you can build a service by doing:

```
service = build(api_name, api_version)
```

I am trying to build a service for GoogleDrive, but am having trouble entering in the correct information:

```
>>> from apiclient.discovery import build
>>> service=build('drive', '1.3')
```

Is there a place to find out all the names and versions? And how would I build a service for the most recent GoogleDrive API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the most recent version, you can use `__version__`

[https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/apiclient/**init**.py](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/apiclient/__init__.py)